# Is it possible to add current logged in user's id along with php form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making an app that creates a profile for a sports team. What i need it to do when im adding the team info is that the currently logged in user's ID is added to the team_info table which is as :

```
create table team_info(
    team_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    sport varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    country varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    city_town varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    age_profile varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (team_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_info(user_id)
    );
```

the form is:

```
<?php $userId = $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>
<div id="main">
    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="add_team_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_team"/>
        <h2>Create New Team</h2>
        <label>Team Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>Sport:</label>
        <input type="text" name="sport" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>Country:</label>
        <input type="text" name="country" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>City/Town:</label>
        <input type="text" name="city_town" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>Age Profile:</label>
        <input type="text" name="age_profile" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $userId ?>" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and heres the login_exec.php :

```
<?php

//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('model/connection.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$email = clean($_POST['email']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);
$usertype = $_GET['user_type_id'];

//Input Validations
if ($email == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if ($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if ($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry1 = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND user_type_id = '1'";
$result1 = mysql_query($qry1);

$qry2 = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND user_type_id = '2'";
$result2 = mysql_query($qry2);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 1) {
    //Login Successful
    session_regenerate_id();
    $user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $user_info['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $user_info['email'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $user_info['password'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE'] = $user_info['user_type_id'];
    session_write_close();
    header("location: userPage.php");
    exit();
} else if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 1) {
    //Login Successful
    session_regenerate_id();
    $user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $user_info['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $user_info['email'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $user_info['password'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE'] = $user_info['user_type_id'];
    session_write_close();
    header("location: playerPage.php");
    exit();
} else {
    //Login failed
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'email and password not found';
    $errflag = true;
    if ($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

**SOLUTION**
I found the solution, i had to add session_start() to my form file to access the session data.

Here's the full code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<div id="main">
    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="add_team_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_team"/>
        <h2>Create New Team</h2>
        <label>Team Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>Sport:</label>
        <input type="text" name="sport" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>Country:</label>
        <input type="text" name="country" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>City/Town:</label>
        <input type="text" name="city_town" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>Age Profile:</label>
        <input type="text" name="age_profile" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value='<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] ?>' />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting them in the form is waiting for abuse (people can just change the value / post a different value). Just read it from the session when you want to store it.

Comment: iv added in the login_exec.php file, are you saying i should use $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] when i want to store the user_id ?

Comment: Yes, just use that value instead of one from the `$_POST` array when inserting into the database.

Comment: like this <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] ?>" /> ??

Comment: NO! Do **not** have that element in the form. Forget about having the element there. _At the point you are doing something with the result of the form_, there is where you get the id from the session. Do not _have_ it in your form, do _not trust_ anything in your form.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I don't see it straight, but why not add another hidden input field?

```
<input type="hidden" name="currently_logged_in_user_id" value="<?php echo $userId; ?>" />
```

Comment: I have already, im not sure why its shown in black font, its there just after the <input type="submit" value="Create" />